# HTML Flows Strange (a content appearing in a wrong place?)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm new to css/html and I've been learning it on school, and we just got introduce to Javascript and so.
We're currently developing a project, of a site.

But, when I tried to put together the content with the navbar, something strange happened, when you try to resize to 620px or less, the nav should be 100% width and 20% height and that's ok.

So, my idea was "why don't I just put the content position relative 20% top? so it will fit perfectly" but it doesn't happen. Also, since the content is located down in the html, shouldn't it show under the menu itself? even without positions?

https://codepen.io/kauegatto/full/qJYaxL

Here's the code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#ativarmenu").click(function() {
    $("#menu").slideToggle();
  });
});
```

```css
/* ORGANIZAÇÃO GERAL*/

*,
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background: #fafafa;
}

#clearfix {
  clear: both;
}


/* BARRINHA LATERAL*/

#nav {
  width: 13%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #222;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  float: left;
  color: #fafafa;
}

#logo {
  width: 95%;
  height: 30%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  top: 5%;
}

#logo img,
#logoresponsive img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#logoresponsive {
  display: none;
}

#menu {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  background: #222;
  color: #fafafa;
  position: relative;
  top: 5%;
}

#links {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  top: 15%;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 10% 0;
  width: 100%;
}

#nav li a {
  font-size: 20px;
}

#nav a {
  color: #fafafa;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

#nav li:hover a {
  color: #5271ff;
}


/* Hamburguer */

#hamburguer {
  display: none;
}

#nav li a {
  font-size: 17.5px;
}


/* tamanho do CONTEUDO */

#conteudo {
  width: calc(100% - 13%);
  left: 13%;
}


/* RESPONSIVE */

@media only screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  #nav li a {
    font-size: 15px;
  }
  #nav {
    width: 15%;
  }
  /* CONTEUDO */
  #conteudo {
    width: calc(100% - 15%);
    left: 15%;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 920px) {
  #nav li a {
    font-size: 13px;
  }
  #nav {
    width: 18%;
  }
  /* CONTEUDO */
  #conteudo {
    width: calc(100% - 18%);
    left: 18%;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 810px) {
  #nav li a {
    font-size: 15px;
  }
  #nav {
    width: 22%;
  }
  /* CONTEUDO */
  #conteudo {
    width: calc(100% - 22%);
    left: 22%;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 680px) {
  #menu,
  #logo {
    display: none;
  }
  #logoresponsive {
    display: block;
  }
  #nav {
    width: 100%;
    height: 20%;
  }
  #nav a {
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 100%;
  }
  #nav li:hover a {
    color: #0097e6;
  }
  #logoresponsive {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    width: 30%;
    top: 0;
    min-width: 110px;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  #ativarmenu {
    width: 7.5%;
    height: 5%;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    left: 5%;
    top: -50%;
  }
  #hamburguer,
  #hamburguer::before,
  #hamburguer::after {
    width: 70%;
    background: #fafafa;
    height: 33.3%;
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
  }
  #hamburguer {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  }
  #hamburguer::after,
  #hamburguer::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
  #hamburguer::before {
    bottom: 300%;
  }
  #hamburguer::after {
    bottom: -300%;
  }
  #menu {
    width: 50%;
    height: 80%;
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 20%;
    color: #fafafa;
  }
  #menu li a {
    font-size: 16px;
  }
  /* CONTEUDO */
  #conteudo {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    top: 20%;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 290px) {
  #menu li a {
    font-size: 12px;
  }
}


/* CONTEUDO PRINCIPAL */

#conteudo {
  clear: both;
  background: #666;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta author="kaue e nicollas" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilo.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="main">
    <div id="nav">
      <div id="logo">
        <img src="img/logo.png" alt="logo" width="80%" />

      </div>
      <div id="logoresponsive">
        <img src="img/logoresponsive.png" alt="logo" height="80%" />
      </div>
      <div id="ativarmenu" />
      <div id="hamburguer"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="menu">
      <div id="links">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Produtos</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Configurações</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sobre</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Quem Somos?</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="conteudo">

    <h2>Noticias</h2>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

obs: 
1 - Logos are working, I just don't have the direct link.

2- get the full view otherwise it might glitch.

Objective: Make the content (conteudo) fit the whole screen, except for the nav, fix the problems that I'm currently having (It's showing over the navbar, when it gets on media query of 680px).

If you found this post confusing, comment please, I'm either not from the USA nor a country that speaks English

Comment: The "specific" coding question is unclear here... What You need help because you are new to html/css? mm okay. Then read [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) about how to ask about reproducable issue. -- Otherwise, be more specific and post your code.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette Check edits to see if helped :)

Comment: Remove your `position:fixed` on mobiles.

Comment: And set a height, that is not percentage based.

Comment: Here you go.. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BqxdZo

Comment: Also - If you still want a percentage based height, you could use `20vh` instead - but remember that it will be pretty high on tablets etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your posistion `fixed` on mobile devices, forces the box to only take the viewport into consideration

Remove that and set it to relative, and give the header a fixed height instead of percentage based.

You still need to fiddle with the other placements - but this will get you on the right track regarding the header.

```js
  $(document).ready(function(){
   $("#ativarmenu").click(function(){
     $("#menu").slideToggle();
   });
  });
```

```css
/* ORGANIZAÇÃO GERAL*/
*,html{
 margin:0;
 padding: 0;
}

body{
 background:#fafafa;
}
#clearfix{
 clear:both;
}

/* BARRINHA LATERAL*/

#nav{
 width: 13%;
 height: 100%;
 background: #222;
 position: fixed;
 left: 0;
 float: left;
 color:#fafafa;

}

#logo{
 width: 95%;
 height: 30%;
 margin: 0 auto;
 position: relative;
 top: 5%;
}
#logo img, #logoresponsive img{
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
#logoresponsive{
 display: none;
}
#menu{
 width: 100%;
 height: 50%;
 background:#222;
 color:#fafafa;
 position: relative;
 top: 5%;
}
#links{
 width: 100%;
 position: relative;
 top:15%;
}
li{
 list-style: none;
 text-align: center;
 margin: 10% 0;
 width: 100%;
}

#nav li a{
 font-size: 20px;
}
#nav a{
 color:#fafafa;
 text-decoration: none;
 text-align: center;
 width: 100%;
}
#nav li:hover a{
 color:#5271ff;


}
/* Hamburguer */

#hamburguer{
 display: none;
}
#nav li a{
 font-size: 17.5px;
}

/* tamanho do CONTEUDO */
 #conteudo{
  width: calc(100% - 13%);
  left: 13%;
 }

/* RESPONSIVE */
@media only screen and (max-width: 1000px){
  #nav li a{
 font-size: 15px;
}
 #nav{
  width: 15%;
 }

 /* CONTEUDO */
  #conteudo{
   width: calc(100% - 15%);
   left: 15%;
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 920px){
  #nav li a{
 font-size: 13px;
}
 #nav{
  width: 18%;
 }

 /* CONTEUDO */
  #conteudo{
   width: calc(100% - 18%);
   left: 18%;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 810px){
  #nav li a{
 font-size: 15px;
}

#nav{
 width: 22%;
}

/* CONTEUDO */
 #conteudo{
  width: calc(100% - 22%);
  left: 22%;
 }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 680px){
  
  
  
 #menu,#logo{
  display: none;
 }
 #logoresponsive{
  display: block;
 }
 #nav{
   width: 100%;
   
    position:relative;
    height: 110px;
  }
  
 

 #nav a{
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 100%;
 }
 #nav li:hover a{
  color:#0097e6;
 }
  #logoresponsive{
  position: relative;
   height: 100%;
  width: 30%;
  top: 0;
  min-width: 110px;
   margin: 0 auto;
  }

  #ativarmenu {
      width: 7.5%;
      height: 5%;
      cursor: pointer;
      position: relative;
      left: 5%;
      top: -50%;
  }
 #hamburguer, #hamburguer::before, #hamburguer::after{
   width: 70%;
   background: #fafafa;
   height: 33.3%;
   border-radius: 5px;
   cursor: pointer;
   display: block;
  }

 #hamburguer {
     position: absolute;
     top: 50%;
     left: 50%;
     transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 }
 #hamburguer::after, #hamburguer::before{
   content:"";
   position: absolute;
   left: 0;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
 }
 #hamburguer::before{
   bottom: 300%;
 }
 #hamburguer::after{
   bottom: -300%;
 }

 #menu{
  width: 50%;
  height: 80%;
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top:20%;
  color:#fafafa;
 }
 #menu li a{
  font-size: 16px;
 }

/* CONTEUDO */
 #conteudo{
  width:100%;
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  top: 20%;
 }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 290px)
{
 #menu li a{font-size:12px;}

}

/* CONTEUDO PRINCIPAL */
#conteudo{
 clear: both;
 background: #666;
 position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8"/>
 <meta author="kaue e nicollas"/>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilo.css">
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="main">
  <div id="nav">
   <div id="logo">
    <img src="img/logo.png" alt="logo" width="80%"/>

   </div>
   <div id="logoresponsive">
    <img src="img/logoresponsive.png" alt="logo" height="80%"/>
   </div>
   <div id="ativarmenu"/>
    <div id="hamburguer"></div>
   </div>
   <div id="menu">
    <div id="links">
     <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Produtos</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Configurações</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sobre</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Quem Somos?</a></li>
     </ul>
    </div>
   </div>
</div>
  <div id="conteudo">

   <h2>Noticias</h2>
  </div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

place all css in different screens

```
 @media screen and (min-width:769px){
   ...
    nav{
        width:20%;
    }
    ...
}
@media screen and (max-width:768px){
    ...
     nav{

       width:100%;
       height:20%;
    }
    .content{

        top:20%;
        height:80% ;
     }
    ...
}
```

also can use relative values like

```
.logo{
    margin-top:20%;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but that didn't work. I mean, since the "content" or  conteudo" like in code is on the top, it will create a margin in the top https://prnt.sc/l7rolc